# Rx.js observable subscribe - button click not caught

Tags: rxjs, observable

I'm trying a very basic example with Rx.js observable-subscribe. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meter>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.js"></script>
<script  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>

<button id='testButton'>Click</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var button = $('#testButton');
var btn$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

btn$.subscribe(function(e){
    console.log(e);
});
```

But there is nothing in the console when I click the button. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped my JS code to jquery '$( document ).ready()' handler and it started working:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var button = $('#testButton');

    var btn$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

    btn$.subscribe(function(e){
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`fromEvent` requires the first argument to be DOM element. `$` probably refers to `jQuery` which returns a jQuery object.

So you should pull the native element from `button` before passing it to `fromEvent`:

```
var button = $('#testButton');
var btn$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(button[0], 'click'); // or .get(0) instead of [0]
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lpvsng?file=index.ts

Comment: I tried this and got the error after browser refresh: Rx.js:3642 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid event target
    at Function.FromEventObservable.setupSubscription (Rx.js:3642)
    at FromEventObservable._subscribe (Rx.js:3664)
    at FromEventObservable.Observable._trySubscribe (Rx.js:893)
    at FromEventObservable.Observable.subscribe (Rx.js:881)
    at index.js:35

Comment: It does work for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-lpvsng?file=index.ts

Comment: Ye, and in your sandbox it even works without '[0]' for button. Looks like it depends on how scripts are loaded - I'm just testing this simply in browser.